# What is wrong with the following for loop? It runs into syntax error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ISOQuestionnaire_Format (1).xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


while True:
    row = 2
    column = 6
    a = sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column = column-2).value
    for a == None:
        print(sheet.cell(row,column).value)
        row+=1
```

It shows syntax error at first line of for loop. What is wrong with it?

Error like:

```
File "xljson.py", line 11
   for a == None:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What do you want this loop to be doing?  It's so far from being a valid statement that it's hard to suggest a good fix, other than just deleting that line and unindenting the following block.

Comment: Please include the error message verbatim.

Comment: @jarmod it should be something basic like "invalid syntax", because `for a == None` isn't a valid `for` statement.

Comment: @Samwise agreed, but you should never report a problem without the actual text of the error message.

Comment: @Samwise then can you suggest an alternative for that?

Comment: `print("Hello World!")`

Comment: @huntethan008, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this `for a==None:` cycle?

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
    for a == None:
```

is basically nonsensical.  A `for` in Python is supposed to iterate over something, and you haven't supplied an iterable.

I'm going to take a wild stab and guess that you might be aiming for something more like this...?

```
row = 2
column = 6
while True:
    a = sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column = column-2).value
    if a is None:
        break
    print(sheet.cell(row,column).value)
    row+=1
```